# Como coletar dados de um Json

Tags: javascript, json

Como posso pegar os dados do arquivo json no script.js para apresentar no html?

```js
//Arquivo Json
[
  {
    "MATRICULA": 211012094044,
    "NOME": "ALICYA NHAYARA SILVA ANDRADE",
    "CURSO": "ADMINISTRACAO",
    "CIDADE": "ITABAIANA",
    "TURMA": "A0",
    "NOTA": 621.9,
    "POSICAO": "24º",
    "ESTADO": "SE"
  },
  {
    "MATRICULA": 211029189431,
    "NOME": "ANA CLARA DE SOUZA CRUZ",
    "CURSO": "ADMINISTRACAO",
    "CIDADE": "ITABAIANA",
    "TURMA": "A0",
    "NOTA": 655.9,
    "POSICAO": "6º",
    "ESTADO": "SE"
  }]
```

Utilizei o fetch como mencionado porem estava dando erro, fiz algumas mudanças para conseguir demonstrar o que pode estar causando erro, ainda não consegui resolver.

```js
const url = "./Dados.json";
  fetch(url).then((response) => {
    console.log("Response:", response);
    return response.json();
  });
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwcvQ.png)

Comment: Não deveria existir a última virgula no arquivo json, em `},]`

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo que o arquivo .json esteja no mesmo lugar que que a pagina html no servidor. A pagina e script serão executados no navegador do cliente que não tem acesso ao arquivo Dados.json. Então é necessário fazer um [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) nesse arquivo no seu script para o navegador baixar o arquivo do servidor. Segue exemplo:

```js
async function logJson() {
  const resposta = await fetch('./Dados.json')
  const json = await resposta.json()
  console.log(json)
}

logJson();
```

Comment: Esta dando este erro: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Não é necessário usar o `JSON.parse`. No exemplo eu utilizo o `.json()` na resposta

Comment: Não estou usando o JSON.parse, estou utilizando como no exemplo de resposta.